# Can Jetty compile *.java files by automation?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jetty

Structure of my application is:

```
/app
 |-src
 ||-Test.java
 |-WebContent
 ||-test.jsp
 ||-WEB-INF
 ||..
```

Configuration file fragment:

```
...
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="resourceBase">/app/WebContent/</Set>
    <Set name="extraClasspath">/app/src/</Set>
</New>
...
```

*test.jsp*:

```
<%
Test test;
%>
```

Error message from *test.jsp*:

```
PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
```

How can I get *Test.class* (According to *Test.java*) by automation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty can not compile anything, it is just web-server.
Use maven to deploy your project in jetty.
Maven compiles all *.java files automatically.